# Count active users within last week?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB database with objects created by different users. Now to track user retention and active users, once a week I want find out how many different users has created a new object.

For instance, let's say the objects are "Notes". How can I, in an effective way, count how many different users has created a note within the last week?

A Note:

```
{
   "user_id" : "..."
   "note"    : "..."
   "date"    : "..."
}
```

I use mongoose and NodeJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that the collection is attached to a model named `Note` and the data in `"date"` is actually a valid `Date` object, then you essentially query the data for between the given dates and aggregate:

```
// Work out days for start of tomorrow and one week before
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      oneWeek = oneDay * 7;

const d = Date.now();
const lastDay  = d - ( d % oneDay ) + oneDay;
const firstDay = lastDay - oneWeek;

// Run the aggregation

Note.aggregate([
  // $match is a query to select the week
  { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": new Date(firstday), "$lt": new Date(lastDay) } },

  // $group on the distinct users
  { "$group": { "_id": "$user_id" } },

  // $group to count the total
  { "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }
],function(err, results) {
  // results in here
})
```

The [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is a "query" just like any other MongoDB query statement. You use the [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operators to represent the "range" of values that can fall in between. This is actually a shorthand way of writing an AND condition without explicitly stating the term.

The next stage is a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) which we use to "aggregate" the `"user_id`" field data as "distinct" values by applying to the grouping key, which is `_id`. The output of a grouping key is always unique.

The last stage is another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), where this time the grouping key is `null` rather than using a present field value. This means *"group everything"*, so we end up with a single row which applies the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operation on the value of `1` to effect the "count".

This is how aggregation "pipelines" work, as each "stage" flows into the next. So "Query" -> "Aggregate Distinct" -> "Aggregate Total", is the pattern, where the most important thing to remember is that each stage can only see the view of the data that was output from the previous stage.

Once you get those concepts, this is easy.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this elaborate answer! I will definitely look more into aggregation :)